# snap folder in /root/

Tags: root, snap

I've just noticed a `snap` folder in the `/root/` directory of a reasonably new server running Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS. It contains a single folder `/root/snap/` containing `/root/snap/lxd`.

I didn't intentionally do that. I wonder whether it should be there and whether I should do anything about it.

There is also a `/snap` folder that also contains `/snap/lxd`, etc.

Please advise or direct/point me at documentation that I haven't yet found.

Answer (score 4):

Snaps have been part of Ubuntu Server for a little while and can be quite useful for people who want to make use of the Snap feature set. There are a number of snaps that are logical to keep on an Ubuntu Server installation, too, such as [NextCloud](https://snapcraft.io/nextcloud) and a number of popular VPN tools. This allows for the software to always remain up to date without being babysat by an administrator. This can be particularly useful for people who want to "set and forget" while still benefitting from new security updates.

Fortunately, if you do not need or want your Ubuntu Server to use snaps, you can remove `snapd` without consequences.

```
sudo apt remove snapd
```

One thing you will want to check beforehand is that you're not using any OpenVPN tools that run as a snap. You can do this with:

```
snap list
```

This is what people will see with a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 installation on Amazon:

```
Name              Version    Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
amazon-ssm-agent  3.0.161.0  2997   latest/stable/…  aws✓        classic
core              16-2.48    10578  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18            20201210   1949   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
lxd               4.0.4      18152  4.0/stable/…     canonical✓  -
```

So long as nothing in that list is necessary, feel free to remove it. If you change your mind later, simply:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Hope this answers your question.